# Can the blog articles have a tweet button?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, twitter

Can the blog articles have a tweet button? IMHO the blog articles written are well worth sharing...Server Fault's latest article "[Technology, not Products](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/technology-not-products/)" is a great example.

I know that Jeff & Co usually mention new blog articles on twitter of which they can re-tweeted if you are following them but it would be quite useful if you could provide similar functionality to the Questions for the blog articles.

Comment: I've notified our sysadmins of this request.